# What do you call a "section" of a sector?

Tags: geometry, circles

I"d like to know if there is a formal name for the following shape.

If you take say a sector of a circle of radius 2 and then remove the sector of radius 1 from that larger sector. What do you call the remaining shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape you are working on as a name: it is an [annulus sector](https://rechneronline.de/pi/annulus-sector.php).

Comment: Great. Looking into that I see that "annulus sector" (compound noun), "annular(adj) sector" and "sector of an annulus" are all acceptable.